# How to convert a unix timestamp to a String with timezone in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

For example, I have a timestamp `1662012433` and I want to convert it to a String with a local timezone (Hong Kong time UTC+8) which would be `2022-09-01 14:07:13 UTC+0800` or `2022-09-01 14:07:13 HKT`.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution easiest with help of [`chrono-tz`](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono-tz)

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc, NaiveDateTime};
use chrono_tz::Tz;

let timestamp = NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp(1662012433, 0);
let utc_time = timestamp.and_local_timezone(Utc).unwrap();
let tz:Tz = "Asia/Hong_Kong".parse().unwrap();
let hkt = utc_time.with_timezone(&tz);
assert_eq!(hkt.to_string(), "2022-09-01 14:07:13 HKT".to_string());
```